# What is the fastest bzip2 decompressor?

Tags: performance, compression, bzip2

Which implementation of bzip2 have the biggest decompression speed?

There is a http://bitbucket.org/james_taylor/seek-bzip2/src/tip/micro-bunzip.c which claims

> Size and speed optimizations by
>   Manuel Novoa III  (mjn3@codepoet.org).
>   More efficient reading of huffman
>   codes, a streamlined read_bunzip() 
>   function, and various other tweaks. 
>   In (limited) tests, approximately  20%
>   faster than bzcat on x86 and about 10%
>   faster on arm.  Note that about 2/3 of
>   the time is spent in read_unzip()
>   reversing  the Burrows-Wheeler
>   transformation.  Much of that time is
>   delay  resulting from cache misses.

A lot of cache misses have a chance to be optimized out by some techniques, so even faster implementations are possible.

This one (seek-bzip2) have also an interesting feature of easy seeking in the input file.

My program will consume output of bzip2 and (Theoretically) can do this in parallel on different parts of file. So, parallel bzip2 implementations are considered too.

Thanks.

Comment: bzip2 0.1 is part of SpecCPU2000, so it must be carefully studied by compiler writers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a bit http://lists.debian.org/debian-mentors/2009/02/msg00135.html of comparison. Parallel versions are considered.

A bit also there http://realworldtech.com/forums/index.cfm?action=detail&id=98883&threadid=98430&roomid=2

links are from intel cilk-parallel version of bzip2 http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/a-parallel-bzip2/

Also, Intel's ipp-powered bzip2 is rathee good and also trys in IPP (with negative effect) to parallelize some insides of bzip2 (no parallel block decompression) with openmp (intel KMP 5).
When limiting it to one or two threads, 20 MByte/s of decompressed stream is real on 2.4 core2 (ipp "v8" code)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

[lbzip2](https://lbzip2.org/) is a good alternative.

```
sudo apt install lbzip2

lbzip2 -d <archive>
```

Comment: Adding `-v` prints progress and estimated time to complete.  Super useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to multi processor machines (it's easy to spin a multi processor virtual machine on Amazon EC2 or Digital Ocean) / machines with a lot of RAM, you should definitely check out [PBZIP2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/):

*PBZIP2 is a parallel implementation of the bzip2 block-sorting file compressor that uses pthreads and achieves near-linear speedup on SMP machines*

---

To illustrate: I'm currently decompressing a large 17Gb file. `bzip2` was writing the decompressed file at a rate of 10Mb/sec; PBZIP2 is writing it now at 160Mb/sec. I'm running it thus:

```
pbzip2 -v -d -k -m10000 file.bz2
```

i.e. `-v` verbose `-d` decompress `-k` keep the original file `-m1000` use 10Gb of RAM

This is running on a 64Gb RAM, 20 CPU machine on Digital Ocean which costs $0.952/hour. :-)

Comment: Greg, can you post output of `time pbzip2` or `/usr/bin/time pbzip2` to see the > 100 % cpu usage? Can pbzip2 decompress in parallel any bz2 file or only file compressed with pbzip2?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the original file was not compressed with pbzip2. From what I understand, pbzip2 should be compatible with any bz2 file (please do confirm/disprove). The decompression took ~1 hour, and unfortunately I can't run it now -- but I did definitely see (using `htop`) that all 20 CPUs were used ~100%. Sorry for the unsatisfying response. :-)

Comment: Greg, for better answer (you already shown that 20 cores/threads are possible) you can make similar test with smaller test file (on smaller machine). I will expect that bzip2-compressed file will have no parallel decompression, as pbzip2 format is different: http://compression.ca/pbzip2/ "PBZIP2 Data Format .. Files that are compressed with pbzip2 are broken up into pieces and each individual piece is compressed. .. **Files that are compressed with pbzip2 will also gain considerable speedup when decompressed using pbzip2**. Files that were compressed using **bzip2 will not see speedup**"

Comment: Ha! Very interesting. I will definitely take a look. Thanks